# How can I apply a simple function to multiple columns?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, recode

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("A" = c("y", "y", "n", "n"),
             "B" = c("n", NA, "y", "y"),
             "C" = c("n", "y", "y", "n"))
```

I would like to apply the following code to columns A and B:

```
df$A <- 
  df$A %>% 
  recode(
    "n" = "No",
    "y" = "Yes"
  ) %>% 
  factor(
    levels = c("No", "Yes")
  )
```

I tried to solve this using the following code using a for loop:

```
cols <- c("A", "B")

for (i in cols) {
  df$i <- 
    df$i %>% 
    recode(
      "n" = "No",
      "y" = "Yes"
    ) %>% 
    factor(
      levels = c("No", "Yes")
    )
}
```

However, I get this erroe message:

```
Error in UseMethod("recode") : 
  no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Can anybody help me what I am missing here? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr::across` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("A" = c("y", "y", "n", "n"),
                 "B" = c("n", NA, "y", "y"),
                 "C" = c("n", "y", "y", "n"))

mutate(df, across(c(A, B), ~ recode(.x, "n" = "No","y" = "Yes") %>% factor(levels = c("No", "Yes"))))
#>     A    B C
#> 1 Yes   No n
#> 2 Yes <NA> y
#> 3  No  Yes y
#> 4  No  Yes n
```

Comment: Thank you!! Can you tell me, why the .x inside the recode function is needed?

Comment: To stick more closely to your code you could also do `.x %>% recode("n" = ...`)`. That's just a matter of habit or taste.

Comment: What I meant is, why .x is needed even though we haven't supplied this argument? I'm still new to R so I may be missing a basic concept. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. What we are doing under the hood is we apply a function to each column specified with across, i.e. we could have used `function(x) recode(x, ...)`. `~ recode(.x, ..)` is just short-hand notation where `~` tells R here comes a function and `.x` (or even shorter just `.`) tells R what's the function argument, i.e. `.x` is a special notation you meet quite often when using functions from dplyr or the tidyverse in general.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes a lot more sense now. One last question: do you have any idea why my original code using a for loop does not work?

Comment: Yep. That's because you used `$`, i.e. using `df$i` R looks for a column with name `i` in df. Instead use `df[[i]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `factor` by specifying both its `levels` and `labels` arguments:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df, across(c(A, B), factor, levels=c("n", "y"), labels=c("No", "Yes")))

#     A    B C
# 1 Yes   No n
# 2 Yes <NA> y
# 3  No  Yes y
# 4  No  Yes n
```

Comment: Is it "best practice" to do it this way?

Comment: If you have few columns, then yes. But if you have many columns, it is better to replace `c(A, B)` expression with something like `all_of(cols)` where `cols` is a character vector containing the column names of variables we want to apply a function on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to final output to be factors you can use `fct_recode` from `forcats.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

cols <- c("A", "B")
df <- df %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols), fct_recode, "No" = "n", "Yes" = "y"))
df

#    A    B C
#1 Yes   No n
#2 Yes <NA> y
#3  No  Yes y
#4  No  Yes n

str(df)

#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ A: Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 2 1 1
# $ B: Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 NA 2 2
# $ C: chr  "n" "y" "y" "n"
```

Comment: Where can I add `ordered = TRUE` within this code?

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Function performing a mapping replacement:
# replaceMultipleValues => function() 
replaceMultipleValues <- function(df, mapFrom, mapTo){
  valueMap <- setNames(mapTo, mapFrom)
  res <- data.frame(
    matrix(
      valueMap[unlist(df)], 
      nrow = nrow(df),
      ncol = ncol(df),
      dimnames = dimnames(df)
    )
  )
  return(res)
}

# Application of the function: 
# data.frame => stdout(console)
replaceMultipleValues(
  df, 
  c("y", "n"), 
  c("yes", "no")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(A:B, ~ str_replace_all(., setNames( c('No', 'Yes'), c('n', 'y')))))
    A    B C
1 Yes   No n
2 Yes <NA> y
3  No  Yes y
4  No  Yes n
```